# simple HTMLform adding two number

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Trying to make a simple form that adds two numbers.

After entering the two values and running the program the result is both original values.

For example when adding `2` and `3` I get `32`, when adding `3` and `5` I get `35`..

```js
function add() {
  var numOne = document.getElementById("numberOne").value;
  var numTwo = document.getElementById("numberTwo").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = numOne + numTwo;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Number One <input type="text" id="numberOne" /> Number Two <input type="text" id="numberTwo" />
  <input type="button" value="add" onClick="add()">
</form>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
var result = parseInt(numOne) + parseInt(numTwo);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
```

Whenever you're using *document.getElementById("someId").value*  it gets the value of the field as a String so you need to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to concatenate the values you just have to use `toString()` like this

```
var numOne = document.getElementById("numberOne").value.toString();
var numTwo = document.getElementById("numberTwo").value.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they are being read in as strings instead of integers. When using the add operator on strings, they concatenate strings together hence the results (3 + 5 = 35). Instead if both of the variables are integers then your result would add (3 + 5 = 8). Javascript has a built in function called parseint() which will convert the strings to integers.

Answer (score 0):

If this is mathematical addition, you have simply forgotten to parse the the values to int.

```js
function add() {
  var numOne = document.getElementById("numberOne").value;
  var numTwo = document.getElementById("numberTwo").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = parseInt(numOne) + parseInt (numTwo);
}
```

```html
<form>
  Number One <input type="text" id="numberOne" /> Number Two <input type="text" id="numberTwo" />
  <input type="button" value="add" onClick="add()">
</form>
<span id="result"></span>
```

This will add the numbers i.e. mathematically rather than concatenate the string values as you have experienced.
[image]